# How do I make a list of Users and their total number of posts in a given date?

Tags: 7, views

I have D7 and I can already display a list of users with their total number of nodes with Views but how can I make it so that I can choose the date range?
Its like analytics to see if a User has any posts in a given month.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/workspace try this module. you will achieve your goal

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check if using the [Views Date Format SQL](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_date_format_sql) module could be a solution for you. Here are some quotes about it (from its project page):

> ... allows to format date fields using SQL.
>
> The core functionality is to remove the date formatting from render() and put it in query(). I.e. format date values using SQL's DATE_FORMAT rather than PHP's format_date.
>   This is achieved by assigning a new default handler to node 'created' and 'changed' date fields. This handler extends and overrides views's build in views_handler_field_date.
>
> The UI is completely unobtrusive, only a single checkbox "Use SQL to format dates" is added to the handler configuration popup.

Your question is not about creating charts in Drupal, but you may want to refer to [this comment](https://www.drupal.org/node/1237096#comment-7697321) also for an example of how we typically use it within the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) (disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer) module.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this out, right now I use views to list a list of users and their total number of nodes posted, but what I wanted is to make it so that I can see the number of nodes per month,year, specific time period etc.